# GCP impersonating service account to SSH into VM via IAP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to SSH into a VM by impersonating the VM's service account, which has all the permissions configured.

The command I'm using is:

```
gcloud compute ssh cowsay \
   --command="systemctl status" \
   --impersonate-service-account="moo@cowsay.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
   --tunnel-through-iap
```

Initially everything seems fine and I can see the following in the debug outputs:

```
WARNING: This command is using service account impersonation. All API calls will be executed as [moo@cowsay.iam.gserviceaccount.com].
```

However, I receive an error that hints that an OS Login attempt is still being made with the source service account, instead of the impersonated one:

```
HttpForbiddenError: HttpError accessing https://oslogin.googleapis.com/v1/users/source@initial.iam.gserviceaccount.com/loginProfile?projectId=cowsay
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) User [source@initial.iam.gserviceaccount.com] does not have permission to access user [source@initial.iam.gserviceaccount.com] (or it may not exist): End user credentials must match the user specified in the request.
```

Is it possible to use `gcloud compute ssh --impersonate-service-account` to SSH into the instance without granting the source account additional permissions?

Answer (score 2):

You can see in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--impersonate-service-account):

> In order to perform operations as the service account, your currently
>   selected account must have an IAM role that includes the
>   iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken permission for the service account

Try add the role `iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken` to your account.

Comment: Correct! I made sure to give the current service account the token creator role on the target service account `moo@cowsay.iam.gserviceaccount.com` already though .

Comment: I think that you need to add the role to the `source@initial.iam.gserviceaccount.com` account. That in fact is the account that tries to execute the gcloud command.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I've misunderstood that part then. I'm going to try fixing roles now.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I added a IAM binding on the service account `moo@cowsay.iam.gserviceaccount.com` to grant the token creator role to `source@initial.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.